# windows 7 : environment variable not working

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

I added an environment variable "qt" with the value "C:\qt\4.3.4\bin" and also added the path in system variable. the path had the below value and I added new value "C:\qt\4.3.4\bin" to the end of it. but still it doesn't work , any idea what's the problem ?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\qt\4.3.4\bin"
```

Comment: In which way it doesn't work?

Comment: the code that I run use it. so right now the code doesn't work and gives me errors regarding this qt(couldn't find qt file required which is in C:\qt\4.3.4\bin path). It is obvious that the environment variable doesn't work!

Comment: has the code been written by you? The problem is dll loading?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is loading dll files. I recently changed my windows and everything worked before quite well without any problem

Comment: If the path variable is set and you can, from anywhere, run exe files included in bin directory without indicating the path, then path variable is working. But i dont know how the code is trying to find the files. If it depends of a hardcoded path, the path variable will not solve the problem by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem occurs because windows has a limit of 1024 or 2048 chars length in PATH variable.
I wrote a small application to take care this problem and reduce unnecessery text from the PATH environment variable in windows 7.
It simply removes duplicates and removes paths that are no longer valid.

you can try it out here:
https://github.com/AsafShochet/Environment-Path-Variable-Minimizer

Answer (score 1):

Remember to close and re-open the command prompt after applying changes to environmental variables!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If those `***` are literally in your PATH variable value, I think that's the problem.

Check that `C:\qt\4.3.4\bin` exists (and has the executables or DLLs you need) and put it in your path without any strange asterisks.

Comment: no their not , I wanted to show where I added that and just emphasize more ;) and C:\qt\4.3.4\bin exists and has the executables.

Comment: If you start a new command prompt (`cmd`), does it see the new PATH value (`echo %PATH%`) and enable you to run the QT executables?

Comment: Well, the `PATH` variable is OK, then.. so it really depends on what your specific error is. See: http://www.google.com/search?q=qt+environment+variables+windows

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [application](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) to see the Environment Variables. And I have discovered they have a listing of Windows environment variables on one of the pages. It makes quite easy to reduce the path, to use the variable name for part of the name.

HTH